# NSObject to NSString Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsobject

Can someone help me to convert an NSObject to NSString?

I'm trying to do something like this -

```
NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:ivpObj.addressStr];
```

But I got an warning - Format is not a string literal and no format arguments

Please some one help

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about this:

```
NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ivpObj.addressStr];
```

Comment: that means that it's not assigned

Answer (score 3):

Simpler still:

```
NSString *address = [ivpObj.addressStr description];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, it is worked for me

```
NSObject* obj= values[i];
NSString *StringObject= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", obj];
```

Answer (score 0):

it is giving you a warning because you are useing stringWithFormat and you are not passing in a format you just passing in either an NSString or a CString

so chose from on of the other options

```
[NSString stringWithString: ivpObj.addressStr]
[NSString stringWithCString: ivpObj.addressStr encoding: String_Encoding of you addressStr here]
[NSString stringWithUTF8String:ivpObj.addressStr]
```

this should remove your warnings, otherwise if you want to format the string using something similar to Eimantas's answer